# Is there a way to disable to embed Javascript to use from another website?

Tags: javascript

I searched alot regarding this one... i know how can we disable embeding one's webpage to another website but i couldnot figure out how can we disable the javascript to be emebeded to other website.

I mean: for eg: **http://mixmax.website/java.js** is the javascript. So how can i disable it to be embeded on other website like this: 
For eg: there is another website: http://otherwebsite.com which is embedding my javascript like this:

```
 <script src="http://mixmax.website/java.js"> </script>
```

**Is there a way to disable that otherwebsite to embed my javascript?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Generally nothing. The web industry learned years ago that you can make millions of dollars without keeping your source code secret so they stopped caring. The only real way to stop others from using your script is copyright and lawyers. If you still REALLY want to do it just make your script only downloadable by logged-in users. Obviously you can't do it for all your js, just ones important to you. You can also try checking the referrer before serving the script (and send 404 error if referrer is not your site)

Comment: thank you for your comment...but how can i check referrer in my javascript?

Comment: Both the methods above (referrer and login) are checked at the server (PHP, Ruby, node.js etc) not in your javascript